How to automatically add new keys with values to an existing key?
I have the following problem. I want to automatically create with a for function a dictionary with mixed keys as following:

I have the main key which is "books" and for this key I want to add books ( which a new key )  with quantity ( values )
Example: store_dic = {'books': {'book0': 0, 'book1': 1,'book2':2}}

I tried this:
store_dic= dict()

book_list = [[None] for _ in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
    book_list[i] = "book"+str(i)
    store_dic= {'books': {book_list[i] : i}}
print(store_dic)

Currently the dictionary displays only the last key with value inserted in the main key.
Output
{'books': {'book2': 2}}

Please help me update the main key with multiple keys that have values.

you should first assign as value an empty dictionary to the key books then store_dic['books']['bookX'] = i

is book_list a flat list or contains sublists?

A possibility could be to divide the task into two steps, first create the mapping with "enumerated" books then assign it to you main dictionary.
book_list = [[None] for _ in range(3)]

store_dic = dict()
books = {'book'+str(k): k for k in range(len(book_list))}
store_dic['books'] = books

... or a more compact version
book_list = [[None] for _ in range(3)]

store_dic = {}

for i in range(len(book_list)):
    store_dic.setdefault('books', {})['book'+str(i)] = i

or with a dictionary comprehension
book_list = [[None] for _ in range(3)]

store_dic = {
    'books': {'book'+str(i): i for i in range(len(book_list))}
}


Notice that you could use the f-string notation to improve readability, f'book{i}' instead of 'book'+str(i)

Thank you! Managed to implement in my code!!

your bug is you override store_dict each loop, that's why you are getting just one element,
Here is the code you want:
store_dic= dict()

# result = {
#     "books": {
#         "book0": 0,
#         "book1": 1,
#         "book2": 2,
#     }
# }

store_dic["books"] = {}
book_list = [[None] for _ in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
    store_dic["books"]["book%s"%str(i)] = i

print(store_dic)

The output :
{'books': {'book0': 0, 'book1': 1, 'book2': 2}}


the output should be just a nested dictionary, values not stored in a list

@cards Yes, I need nested dictionary. Can be done?

@i33SoDA the code is updated and now the output is nested dict
